# Does ConcurrentMap.remove() provide a happens-before edge before get() returns null?

Tags: java, concurrency

Are actions in a thread prior to calling `ConcurrentMap.remove()` guaranteed to *happen-before* actions subsequent to seeing the removal from another thread?

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) says this regarding objects placed into the collection:

> Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into any concurrent collection happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the collection in another thread.

Example code:

```java
{
    final ConcurrentMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    map.put(1, new Object());

    final int[] value = { 0 };

    new Thread(() -> {
        value[0]++;
        value[0]++;
        value[0]++;
        value[0]++;
        value[0]++;

        map.remove(1); // A

    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        if (map.get(1) == null) { // B
            System.out.println(value[0]); // expect 5
        }

    }).start();
}
```

Is *A* in a *happens-before* relationship with *B*?  Therefore, should the program only, if ever, print 5?

Comment: Why would you think otherwise, given the documentation you've quoted?

Comment: @shmosel This particular text states *Actions prior to placing an object* happens-before, but nothing about actions prior to removal of an object.

Comment: Any particular reason you singled out `ConcurrentMap` from other concurrent collection types?

Comment: @shmosel I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but it's what I was using when the question arose, and what I'm currently interested in an answer to.

Answer (score 6):

You have found an interesting subtle aspect of these concurrency tools that is easy to overlook.

First, it’s impossible to provide a general guaranty regarding removal and the retrieval of a `null` reference, as the latter only proves the *absence* of a mapping but not a previous *removal*, i.e. the thread could have read the map’s initial state, before the key ever had a mapping, which, of course, can’t establish a *happens-before* relationship with the actions that happened after the map’s construction.

Also, if there are multiple threads removing the same key, you can’t assume a *happens-before* relationship, when retrieving `null`, as you don’t know which removal has been completed. This issue is similar to the scenario when two threads insert the same value, but the latter can be fixed on the application side by only perform insertions of distinguishable values or by following the usual pattern of performing the desired modifications on the value object which is going to be inserted and to query the retrieved object only. For a removal, there is no such fix.

In your special case, there’s a *happens-before* relationship between the `map.put(1, new Object())` action and the start of the second thread, so if the second thread encounters `null` when querying the key `1`, it’s clear that it witnessed the sole removal of your code, still, the specification didn’t bother to provide an explicit guaranty for this special case.

Instead, the specification of [Java 8’s `ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says,

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a *happens-before* relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

clearly ruling out `null` retrievals.

I think, with the current (Java 8) `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation, your code can’t break as it is rather conservative in that it performs all access to its internal backing array with `volatile` semantics. But that is only the *current* implementation and, as explained above, your code is a special case and likely to become broken with every change towards a real-life application.

Comment: +1: All in all, I agree with your reasoning, but your second and third paragraphs make generalized statements though they only apply to certain usages (including probably a usage deduced from my example).  e.g. If I'm using the map to provide exclusion over some critical section, *absence* is exactly what I want to prove, and that in itself should be fine, if not for the situation that removal may or may not provide a guarantee that work done during the critical section is propagated. https://gist.github.com/atnak/f64b8cdb6fe5042cfdc05f7c25411996?ts=4

Comment: @antak: sure, if absence is what you want to prove, everything is fine. The point here is, that absence doesn’t establish a *happens-before* relationship with the removal. Note that guarding critical sections via presence or absence of a mapping isn’t different to critical sections guarded by a `Lock`. A successful lock operation alone is not sufficient to prove the existence of a previous unlock operation, you have to query the shared state to find out which operations have been done.

Comment: Guarding a critical section with a `Lock` **is** different.  A successful lock operation is enough to prove that ***if*** there was a previous unlock operation, anything done to the shared state by the unlocking thread *before* the unlock has *already happened* and not ongoing.  With an absence of mapping, it's not even safe (as your answer establishes?) to query the shared state because actions performed on it may be, or may appear to be, ongoing.  The shared state itself needs to be `volatile` or have some other synchronizing property for this to be safe.

Comment: Exactly. Both, the state of a `Lock` and the presence/absence of a mapping in a `ConcurrentMap` can be used to ensure *mutual exclusion* of a critical section, but only the `Lock` allows you to access the shared state with a *happens-before* relationship.

Answer (score 1):

As ConcurrentHashMap is a thread safe collection, the statement `map.remove(1)` must have a read barrier and a write barrier if it alters the map. The expression `map.get(1)` must have a read barrier or one, or both of those operations are not thread safe.

In reality ConcurrentHashMap up to Java 7, uses partitioned locks, so it always has a read/write barrier for nearly every operation.

A  ConcurrentSkipListMap doesn't have to use locks, but to perform any thread safe write action, a write barrier is required.

This means your test should always act as expected.

Comment: Why must `remove()` have a write barrier?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @shmosel can you say why it doesn't answer your question as I must be missing something?

Comment: I just want to understand if and where it's documented that there's a write barrier on removal. Even if `ConcurrentHashMap` happens to create a barrier, that's no guarantee for future implementations. Besides, OP seems to be asking about the `ConcurrentMap` interface rather than a particular implementation.

Comment: @shmosel Ah, so that's what you meant by your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341742/does-concurrentmap-remove-provide-a-happens-before-edge-before-get-returns-n#comment66014861_39341742).  Yes, I wrote `ConcurrentMap` for conciseness and because a generic answer is always ideal, but information regarding `ConcurrentHashMap` is just as appreciated because that what I'm using.

Comment: @shmosel When a class says it is thread safe, it would be redundant to have to spell out what that means for every method.  There is no way to perform a thread safe write without a write barrier.

Comment: By read/write barrier, I assume you mean a consistency mechanism that encompasses everything javac / JVM could do, including instruction reordering and value caching, and not the CPU instruction.  When I saw the term, I thought your answer might be platform dependent, but your last few edits have clarified it somewhat.

Comment: "Thread safe" can mean different things depending on the context. `ConcurrentHashMap` explicitly allows for weakly consistent iteration and overlapping reads and writes. Why assume a happens-before relationship between writes and reads unless clearly documented? In fact, the quote in the question (which is repeated on the `ConcurrentMap` interface) would seem to imply that these relationships can't be taken for granted and they're only guaranteed in the specified case.

Comment: More specifically, the documentation states, "The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation *happens-before* the read operation." This is clearly not the case in OP's question.

Comment: @shmosel can you give an example of how you could perform remove in a thread safe manner without a write barrier being used?

Comment: @shmosel could explain how this might mean you don't see the expected value. I can see you are not convinced but I don't understand what you imagine might happen.

Comment: That depends again on what "thread safe" means. All I know for certain is that the element would be removed *at some point* and it would never throw an exception. Maybe I'm completely missing the point of concurrent collections. All I'm asking for is a source.

Comment: Here's an excerpt from the ConcurrentHashMap documentation: *"Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)"*

Comment: @shmosel in the OP's code, there is a check for whether the remove is visable or not do when it happens doesn't actually matter, the second check only occurs if it is visible.

Comment: *Here's an excerpt from the ConcurrentHashMap*: Hrmm, the emphasis on *non-null* retrieval for a key suggests specifically that *happens-before* should not be taken for granted when null is reported...

Comment: @antak in reality I think it doesn't, but it can't be taken for granted based on the Javadoc and indeed your code doesn't read the array when null is returned.

Comment: Only the `ConcurrentHashMap` before Java 8 uses partitioned locks, starting with Java 8, it works quite different. A good example of why not to rely on a particular implementation’s behavior.

Comment: Actually, before Java 8, there were no mentioning of the *(non-null) retrieval* in the `ConcurrentHashMap` docs. So, one cannot fully rely on the documentation either :)

Comment: @Andrew Lygin: I think, this is not a change in the semantics; before Java 8, updates (not considering removals) were not allowed to use `null`. Now, the `compute…` and `merge` methods were introduced, whose functions are allowed to return `null`, which will cause the mapping to be removed. So the clarification has been added that these update operations are only considered when updating to non-`null`, continuing to exempt removals from *happens-before* with `get`.

Comment: @Holger, your explanation makes sense, but it's all about updates and it's still unclear why the doc talks about *non-null retrievals*. Given the current implementation, there's absolutely no difference in terms of fences between retrieving a null or non-null value. In both cases there's one volatile read of a node in the table.

Comment: At the same time, many update operations (including removal) use the same volatile read plus a synchronized block on the node if the value is found. It would make more sense for me if the doc would talk about non-null updates that guarantee happens-before, not non-null retrievals. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Andrew Lygin: a *happens-before* relationship is always established between two actions and here, it’s about updates and subsequent retrievals “*for that key reporting the updated value*”. Since the value must match, it’s irrelevant, on which end you put the non-`null` constraint for the value. Note that the `volatile` read and write of a `Node`’s value only happens if there is a node, i.e. doesn’t happen for removed mappings (hence, `synchronized(node)` has no effect on the thread not seeing the node).

Comment: Regarding the table access, the code itself has [a comment about it being conservative and doing more than necessary](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#747). That’s why I wrote in my answer that the OP’s code will work with the *current implementation* as it might change when the table access gets relaxed in a future implementation…

Comment: @Holger, I agree with this reasoning. I'm just saying that moving this *non-null* remark from the *retrieval* to the *update* (or even its complete removal) would make more sense and would remove the antak's doubts on the correctness of the answer.

Comment: If we have an update and a consecutive retrieval, it's only the update side that can affect the resulting set of fences (depending on null/non-null), not the retrieval's. Even more, if we're talking only about *happens-before*, it's irrelevant if there were null's or non-null's in both operations. Even if we call `remove` with a nonexistent key and then try to retrieve the same key, technically, we will still have happens-before relationship due to load fences. So, for me this non-null-remark looks misleading in the context of *happens-before*.

Comment: @Holger, there's one thing about the volatile read here. It happens regardless of the node existence since it's the exact read that defines if the node exists.

Comment: @Andrew Lygin: just consider the following scenario: thread A performs a volatile read, then, after, say one hundred millilseconds, thread B performs a volatile write. It should be obvious that this can’t establish a *happens-before* relationship, despite both threads having fences. That’s why talking about fences is completely nonsensical. Fences do not enforce orderings. That’s why the specification clearly says that a *happens-before* relationship is established between a volatile write and a *subsequent* volatile read of the *same* variable. The term “fence” doesn’t even appear in the spec

Comment: @Holger, you're right, brining fences here was irrelevant. I just tried to connect all the general information discussed here, the piece of documentation and the example from the question. You did it pretty good in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have the order wrong.

There is a *happens-before* edge from the `put()` to the subsequent `get()`.  That edge is not symmetric, and doesn't work in the other direction.  There is no *happens-before* edge from at `get()` to another `get()` or a `remove()`, or from a `put()` to another `put()`.

In this case, you put an object in the map.  Then you modify another object.  That's a no-no.  There's no edge from the those writes to the `get()` in the second thread, so those writes may not be visible to the second thread.

On Intel hardware, I think this will always work.  However, it isn't guaranteed by the Java memory model, so you have to be wary if you ever port this code to different hardware.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.  The question's not asking whether a `get()` *happens-before* another `get()` or a `remove()`.  A `put()` is also a removal (it returns the previous value) so actions before placing an object happens-before another `put()` on the same element.  You say putting a object then modifying another object is a no-no, but I think this misses the point.  If said actions were performed *before* `put()`ing an entirely different object, they will be visible to another thread that accessed the element regardless.  However, this isn't what I am asking.

Comment: Can you say where in the JLS it specifies that read/write barriers could be limited to just one object.

Comment: @antak When I'm seeing you do is that you modify an object (the array) then you expect a happens before edge from the `remove()` to the `get()`.  The spec doesn't say anything about that.  Even if you are correct about a `put()` also being a removal, it doesn't matter, because there's no `put()` after your writes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That doesn't matter because that's not what he's doing.  He's expecting a happens-before edge from a `remove()` to a `get()`, and the spec is silent about that operation.  Therefore, it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

A does not need to happen before B.

Only the original `put` happens before both. Thus a null at B means that A happened.

However write back of thread local memory cache and instruction order of `++` and `remove` are not mentioned. `volatile` is not used; instead a Map and an array are used to hopefully keep thread data synchrone. On writing the data back, in-order relation should hold again.

To my understanding A could remove and be written back, then the last ++ happen, and something like 4 being printed at B. I would add `volatile` to the array. The Map itself will go fine.

I am far from certain, but as I did not see a corresponding answer, I stick my neck out. (To learn myself.)