# Java ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent value modification visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap, memory-visibility

Let's say I have a concurrent map with collections as value:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.putIfAbsent(8, new ArrayList<>());
```

and I update the value as follows:

```
map.computeIfPresent(8, (i, c) -> {
    c.add(5);
    return c;
});
```

I know that `computeIfPresent` entire method invocation is performed atomically. However, considering this map is accessed by multiple threads concurrently, I'm a little bit concerned about data visibility of the modifications done to the underlying collection. In this case will the value 5 be seen in the list after calling `map.get`

My question is will change to the list be visible in other threads upon calling `map.get` if changes are performed within `computeIfPresent` method call.

Please note that I am aware that changes to the list will not be visible if I were to take reference to the list before doing the update operation. I am unsure if the changes to the list will be visible if I take reference to the list (by calling `map.get`) after the update operation.

I am unsure how to interpret the docs, but it seems to me that happens-before relationship will guarantee visibility of the changes to the underlying collection in this particular case

> More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To clarify your question:

*You're providing some external guarantee such that `Map.computeIfPresent()` is **called before** `Map.get()`.*

You haven't stated how you're doing this, but let's say you're doing it by using something with *happens-before* semantics provided by the JVM.  If this is the case then that alone guarantees `List.add()` is visible to the thread calling `Map.get()` simply by ***association*** of the *happens-before* relationship.

Now to answer the question you're actually asking: As you've noted, there's a *happens-before* relation between update operation `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent()` and the subsequent calling of the access method `ConcurrentMap.get()`.  And naturally, there's a *happens-before* relation between `List.add()` and the end of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent()`.

Put together, answer is **yes**.

There's a guarantee the other thread will see `5` in the `List` obtained through `Map.get()`, *provided* you're guaranteeing `Map.get()` is actually **called after** `computeIfPresent()` ends (as stated in the question).  If the latter guarantee goes foul and `Map.get()` is somehow called before `computeIfPresent()` ends, there's no guarantees to what the other thread will see since `ArrayList` is not thread-safe.

Comment: in such a case what does that *happens-before* from documentation mean at all(that the OP has shown)? And how come that is not an update operation?

Comment: @Eugene You're right, it's an update operation.  I was thinking of something else entirely.  Well that screws up the premise of my answer...

Comment: Editted: backflip on conclusion

Comment: @antak yes I can guarantee that there will be happens-before relation between update operation ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent() and the access. This is guaranteed by the fact that other thread will call `ConcurrentMap.remove`(not `ConcurrentMap.get`) which would mean that update is either performed (5 is added) or it is skipped if the map entry is removed

Comment: @antak *there's no guarantees to what the other thread will see since ArrayList is not thread-safe* how about the fact that documentation says that *Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset* - completed being the keyword here. So in my understanding if we had something like `computeIfPresent(list, c) -> c.addAll(list)`, when you call `get` you can't see some intermediary state, like let's say a List with only some partial adding from `addAll`, if I make sense

Comment: @Eugene documentation says that: ` The entire method invocation is performed atomically`, so I would humbly conclude that if the result of the update is visible, it should be entirely visible

Comment: @MarinVeršić to me, atomic does not mean yet visible without a happens before guarantee; but your conclusion either way seems correct to me; and as such this answer needs a bit rewording to make it correct

Comment: @Eugene What you're saying is true and is valid if `Map.get()` is called after `computeIfPresent()` completes.  However, here's a thought experiment on what happens if `Map.get()` was called before that:  In the most the most extreme case, `Map.get()` could be called before `computeIfPresent()` even starts.  In that case, operations are no different to holding onto a reference to the List somewhere (independent of the ConcurrentMap) and performing unsynchronized access on it.  This is because ...

Comment: @antak please note that I'm actually using `map.remove` instead of `map.get` as stated in the previous comment

Comment: ... This is because, even though one thread may be `add()`ing inside (and hence *happens-before* the completion of) `computeIfPresent()`, that itself doesn't provide synchronization against the List that was retrieved out of the ConcurrentMap much earlier on.  Specifically, the clause cited only applies if `Map.get()` returned the List after `computeIfPresent()`, which was in turn was after `List.add()`, thereby competing the List.add() -> Map.get() happens-before relation by association.

Comment: @MarinVeršić you should have written right in your question that you are talking about `remove`, as `remove` is not a retrieval operation, but an *update* operation. Since update operations are atomic, but retrieval operations are not, it makes a fundamental difference.

Comment: @Holger I see your point, my mistake. I did state that I can guarantee `map.get` will be called after the update operation, but I didn't provide you with the mechanism for doing so. Would you like me to update the original question?

Comment: @MarinVeršić Synchronization with `ConcurrentMap.remove()` [is somewhat involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341742/does-concurrentmap-remove-provide-a-happens-before-edge-before-get-returns-n) and isn't a topic I feel I could give commentary on in the comments section of this answer.  Maybe if you opened another question someone more knowledgeable could offer their expertise.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that that method is documented to be `atomic`, does not mean much about `visibility` (unless that is part of the documentation). For example to make this simpler:

```
// some shared data
private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

public synchronized void addToList(List<Integer> x){
     list.addAll(x);
}

public /* no synchronized */ List<Integer> getList(){
     return list;
}
```

We can say that `addToList` is indeed atomic, only one thread at a time can call it. But once a certain thread calls `getList` - there is simply no guarantee about `visibility` (because for that to be established, [it has to happens on the same lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) ). So visibility is something happens before is concerned with and `computeIfPresent` documentation does not say anything about that, at all.

Instead the class documentation says:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may **overlap** with update operations (including put and remove).

The key point here is obviously *overlap*, so some other threads calling `get` (thus getting a hold of that `List`), can see that `List` in some state; not necessarily a state where `computeIfPresent` started (before you actually called `get`). Be sure to read further to understand what that *some* actually might mean.

And now to the trickiest part of that documentation:

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset. More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a *happens-before* relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.

Read that sentence about *completed* again, what it says is that the only thing you can read when a thread does `get` is the *last completed* state that List was in. And now the next sentence says that there is a *happens before* established between two actions.

Think about it, a `happens-before` is established between *two subsequent* actions (like in the synchronized example above); so internally when you update a `Key` there could be a volatile written signaling that update has finished (I am pretty sure it's not done this way, just an example). For the happens before to actually work, `get` has to read that volatile and see the state that was written to it; if it sees that state it means that *happens before* has been established; and I guess that by some other technique this is actually enforced.

So to answer your question, all the threads calling `get` will see the `last completed action` that happened on that key; in your case if you can guarantee that order, I'd say, yes, they will be visible.

Comment: if I wasn't clear in my question, I can guarantee that `map.get` will be called after `map.computeIfPresent`. So from your answer I conclude that changes to the underlying list will be visible. I will try to emphasize that in the question

Comment: @MarinVeršić I've reworded a bit and answered. whatever you do leave this question un-answered for some time, I've triggered one of  the people I respect here most, and I sure hope that tomorrow we will get a hell of a good answer.

Comment: wow, I really appreciate the effort. I hope I've given enough info to understand the question

Comment: @MarinVeršić keep in mind that “after” means being subsequent in [Synchronization Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4). E.g. slowing down a thread via `Thread.sleep` or counting loops, as well as exchanging information via shared variables in a data race do not count. On the other hand, any action which is truly *after* the other in the synchronization order, is already sufficient for establishing a *happens-before* relationship on its own ad doesn’t even need guarantees from the map.

Comment: @Holger what about if we had `computeIfAbsent(list, c) -> c.addAll(list)`. In my understanding since the documentation says *Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset*, when some thread calls `get` is can't see some partial update from that `addAll` - it either sees all elements being added from `addAll` or none. Is my understand correct?

Comment: @Eugene that’s not valid syntax and their’s no point trying to perform an `addAll` on an *absent* mapping, so it’s not clear what you are aiming at. Especially, as you already wrote in your answer that `get` may overlap with update operations…

Comment: @Holger shoot! that was suppose to be `computeIfPresent`... I don't understand the guarantees given by that `completed` remark taken with `overlap`. On one hand `get` can see *some intermediate* results based on `overlap`; but than what is `completed` suppose to offer

Comment: @Eugene consider `map.computeIfPresent("key", (key,list) -> { list = new ArrayList<>(list); list.add("foo"); list.add("bar"); return list; });`. Since `ArrayList` is not thread safe, this still relies on safe publishing and CHM provides you the necessary guarantees, i.e. the new instance is not accessed, even if `get` operations overlap, but after completion, there is a happen-before relationship to each subsequent retrieval “reporting the updated value”. In other words, if you see the new reference, it will be correctly populated.

Comment: @Holger I think this makes a bit of sense now. As I take it `get` can overlap with an `update`, but it can't see an intermediate result (like let's say only `foo` being added *without* `bar`); it either sees both or none being added. If I have no idea what happened *before* `get`, all I can say is that *some* update operation happened for sure; if I *can* guarantee that `computeIfPresent` happened before my `get` - I will see the List containing both `foo` and `bar` for sure. Right? I wish I could ping you less, but SO is full of wrong answers (or incomplete) :(

Comment: @Eugene the crucial point is that in my example, an new list instance is created which can only be seen when the update has been completed. An overlapping `get` will still see the old reference, to the object which is not touched.

Comment: @Holger what if that wasn't the case? What if I would update the value in place, putting `foo` and `bar` into it?

Answer (score 2):

`c.add(5)` is not thread safe, the internal state of the `c` is not protected by the map.

The exact way of making individual values and insert-use-remove combinations  thread safe and race condition free depends on the usage pattern (synchronized wrapper, copy-on-write, lock free queue, etc).

Comment: and how would you comment this from the docs: `More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value`? If there is a happens-before relation then effects of the change made in the update function modifying the list should be visible to other threads after the operation is finished? If, after the update operation is finished I call `map.get`, shouldn't I get a reference to the updated list?

Comment: @MarinVeršić - You do not necessarily have to touch the internal state of the value _while_ retrieving it (when it is protected by the map), you can do it after, from several threads concurrently. Map only serializes operations with itself, not with the objects it stores.

Comment: @boboah I am only interested in this specific situation where I take the reference to the list from the map with `map.get` strictly after the update operation was performed within the `map.computeIfPresent` method call. So you would still say that visibility will not be guaranteed even in this case?

Comment: For that one thread there is definitely happens-before, but not for any another thread having the list ref  already cached. Also I am almost sure gets are serialized with writes (easy to check - make write last long using a future and see if getter thread also hangs).

Comment: great, I can guarantee that no thread will have a reference to the list before the update operation is performed.

Comment: @MarinVeršić - and also that an update operation is not performed once they have that reference. Reading `ArrayList` while something is writing to it is also not thread safe.